# docker image to docker file through vscode

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am unable to build docker file from docker image. (`docker build -t thisismyfirstdocker .`)

```
PS C:\Docker1\python-image> docker build -t thisismyfrstdocker .  
[+] Building 0.2s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                              docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                                     0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                       0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                         0.0s 
ERROR: failed to solve: the Dockerfile cannot be empty
ERROR: failed to solve: the Dockerfile cannot be empty
```

I am trying to build dockerfile in vscode and expecting to build it but I got the error:

> ERROR: failed to solve: the Dockerfile cannot be empty

Comment: Just to be sure: did you save the Dockerfile after editing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some know issues that cause this:

1. not capitalized dockerfile
2. point to the build by `-f` flag:

   docker build -t thisismyfirstdocker -f somefile .
3. Change `COPY` to `ADD`. ([Here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5170))